# No envía mail de confirmación con phpMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tengo una clase controladora que al invitar a un empleado, tiene que enviar un mail.

```
     if ($_GET['accion'] == 'invitar'){

        $idReunion_fk = $_GET['idReunion_fk'];

        $idEmpleado_fk = $_GET['idEmpleado_fk'];

        $empleado_reunionDao = new Empleado_reunion_DAO();

        $nexo = new Empleado_reunion();

        $nexo->setIdReunion_fk($idReunion_fk);
        $nexo->setIdEmpleado_fk($idEmpleado_fk);
        $nexo->setConfirmacion(0);

        $empleado_reunionDao->insertarNexo($nexo);

        //Tras haber insertado el registro, comienzo con el envío del mail.
        require_once '../model/empleadoDAO.php';

        $empleadoDAO = new EmpleadoDAO();

        require_once '../model/empleadoModelo.php';

        $para = new Empleado();

        //Aquí obtengo el empleado al que quiero mandar el mail
        $para = $empleadoDAO->obtenerEmpleado($idEmpleado_fk );

        //Aquí obtengo su mail
        $para = $para->getEmail();

        $asunto = "asunto del mensaje";

        $mensaje = "<a href='/views/empleados_asistentes.php?".$idReunion_fk."'>aceptar invitación</a>";

        //aquí ejecuto mi función
        enviaMail($para,  $asunto, $mensaje);

    }
```

Aquí tengo mi clase phpMailer:

```
include_once('class.phpmailer.php');

function enviaMail($para,  $asuntoMensaje, $mensaje)
{

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();   // enviar vÌa SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'mail.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // activar la identificacÌn SMTP
    $mail->Username = 'correo@gmail.com'; // usuario SMTP
    $mail->Password = 'contrasena'; // clave SMTP
    $mail->From = "correo@gmail.com"; //remitente
    $mail->FromName = "Sistema de administración de reuniones";//nombre de remitente
    //$mail->AddReplyTo(AppEmailSoporte); //e-mail para respuestas
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    //Destinatarios
    $mail->AddAddress($para); //destinatario

    // Establecemos los par·metros del mensaje: ancho y formato.
    $mail->WordWrap = 50; // ancho del mensaje
    $mail->IsHTML(true); // enviar como HTML

    $mail->Subject = $asuntoMensaje; //Asunto

    $mail->Body = $mensaje; //Cuerpo
    //$mail->AltBody  =  $Mensaje; //Cabecera

    // AÒadimos los adjuntos al mensaje
    //        $mail->AddAttachment("./Manifiestos/".$nombreFichero .".txt"); // podemos aÒadir un adjunto directamente

    if ($mail->Send()){
        //bien
    }else{
        //mal
    }

}
```

La aplicación está alojada en un hosting, y cuando trato de hacer la operación, la consola de google chrome no imprime nada. Mirando ejemplos, aparentemente está todo bien, así que no sé que puede ser....
¿Alguien ve algo raro o tiene idea de como solucionarlo?

Dejo también la ubicación de los archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La clase controladora que realiza la petición de envío está en el archivo empleado_reunion_controlador.php. Se encuentra alojado en una carpeta junto los archivos funcionesMail.php, class.smtp.php y class.phpmailer.php.

Comment: Y qué dice el log de apache? Ahí suelen salir los errores de PHP...

Comment: trabajo con un editor de código... sería posible ver el log de php de alguna manera??

Comment: En el hosting, amigo. AHí debes poder revisar los logs.

Answer (score 0):

Ya intentaste cambiar el numero de puerto,
$mail->Port = 587; 
y poner lo de la seguridad a false,
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;

No tengo mi codigo a la mano, para poder compartirlo.

Comment: no, eso no lo intenté

Comment: Me podrás comentar si con eso ya puede mandar el correo.

Comment: acabo de probarlo pero... tampoco funciona...

Comment: Dame oportunidad de buscar mi código de ejemplo para compartirtelo. Saludos

Comment: No te apures amigo. Ya me funcionó cambiando algunas cosas. También era un problema de recogida de parámetros. Comparto la solución en breve.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Me da gusto que te haya funcionado, puedes votar como la respuesta si gustas.

Comment: Ya he publicado la solución que me funcionó. Espero les sirva al mayor número de personas posible. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente, el problema era el siguiente:

En primer lugar, en mi controlador, no estaba recogiendo bien la dirección mail del usuario. Trataba de acceder a él mediante el DAO, y no era la manera más correcta, ya que esta operación la realizo utilizando ajax e igual que recojo los dos id de manera asíncrona, podía también recoger con ellos el mail:

```
include("class.phpmailer.php");
include("class.smtp.php");
include("funcionesMail.php");

if ($_GET['accion'] == 'invitar') 
{
    $idReunion_fk = $_GET['idReunion_fk'];

    $idEmpleado_fk = $_GET['idEmpleado_fk'];

//Aquí recojo el mail de la misma manera que recojo el id de la reunión y el del empleado:

    $para = $_GET['email'];

    $empleado_reunionDao = new Empleado_reunion_DAO();

    $nexo = new Empleado_reunion();

    $nexo->setIdReunion_fk($idReunion_fk);
    $nexo->setIdEmpleado_fk($idEmpleado_fk);
    $nexo->setConfirmacion(0);

    $empleado_reunionDao->insertarNexo($nexo);

    require_once '../model/empleadoDAO.php';

    $empleadoDAO = new EmpleadoDAO();


    require_once '../model/empleadoModelo.php';  

    $asunto = "asunto del mensaje";

    $mensaje = "<a href='http://rutadelhost.com/views/urldemiaplicacion.php?id=".$idReunion_fk."'>aceptar invitación</a>";

    enviaMail($para,  $asunto, $mensaje);

}
```

Y en segundo lugar, en el archivo de la función mail, tenía mal configurado el puerto, el SMTP y me sobraba un include (los includes van todos en el controlador, como podeís comprobar). El archivo quedaría así:

```
<?php

//Aquí ya no hay ningún include

function enviaMail($para,  $asuntoMensaje, $mensaje)
{

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();   // enviar vÌa SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'nombreddelhost.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // activar la identificacÌn SMTP
    $mail->Username = 'usuariosmtp@ejemplo.net'; // usuario SMTP
    $mail->Password = 'contraseña'; // clave SMTP
    $mail->From = "remitente@gmail.com"; //remitente
    $mail->FromName = "Sistema de administración de reuniones";//nombre de remitente
    //$mail->AddReplyTo(AppEmailSoporte); //e-mail para respuestas

//El puerto es 587
    $mail->Port = 587;

//El SMTPSecure es tls.
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    //Destinatarios
    $mail->AddAddress($para); //destinatario

    // Establecemos los par·metros del mensaje: ancho y formato.
    $mail->WordWrap = 50; // ancho del mensaje
    $mail->IsHTML(true); // enviar como HTML

    $mail->Subject = $asuntoMensaje; //Asunto

    $mail->Body = $mensaje; //Cuerpo
    //$mail->AltBody  =  $Mensaje; //Cabecera

    // AÒadimos los adjuntos al mensaje
    //        $mail->AddAttachment("./Manifiestos/".$nombreFichero .".txt"); // podemos aÒadir un adjunto directamente

    if ($mail->Send()){
        //bien
    }else{
        //mal
    }

}
```